# FBX import texture out of place problem

Tags: uv, .fbx

I am new to Blender and I have looked everywhere for my answer but can't find mine. I imported an FBX file of the Granny model from the horror game. It is rigged. When I import it into Blender, this is what happens to the model

[image: image of texture going crazy]

The animation works perfectly, so I know it's not an armature issue (I hope at least). I have a feeling this has something to do with UV wrapping or something. As I said, I am new to blender so I could use all the help I can get.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Could it be, that you scaled the Mesh? Try selecting the mesh and press "Alt + S"
Also it would be beneficial if we had a https://blend-exchange.com/ file

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your advice. I have tried scaling it up but it seems to have done nothing. I will provide a blend-exchange.com file so you can look at it. https://blend-exchange.com/b/oyJdBqrq